# Duplicate/Clone Node in JavaFX 2.0

Tags: javafx-2

I don't want to load a FXML file twice. It is possible to clone/copy a Node or Group? In JavaFX 1.1 there is a utility class called Duplicater -- is there a pendant in Java FX 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically old `Duplicater` was duplicating FXD formatted nodes. And FXD was substituted with FXML.

So reusing FXML file *is* a JavaFX2 successor of `Duplicater`.