# Clone JavaFX Node?

Tags: java, duplicates, clone, javafx, scenebuilder

I have created a `Node` (`AnchorPane`) in the JavaFX scene builder and was wondering how to clone it.

I saw [Duplicate/Clone Node in JavaFX 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912386/duplicate-clone-node-in-javafx-2-0) but I need to clone the `Node` without re-loading the fxml.

Is there any way to achieve this in JavaFX 2?

Comment: Yeah, I am curious. Without passing through a different .fxml document. Please share

Answer (score 5):

You can place the component that needs to be duplicated in a separate `.fxml` file.

Then you can load the separate file as many times as needed adding the nodes to the appropriate root in the main scene.

Additionally you can edit an `<fx:include source="..."/>` element to the main `.fxml` file and include the separate `.fxml` file. You can then still work with it in the JavaFX Builder.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such node duplication function in the JavaFX platform, you will need to write your own which introspects on the properties of the node you are interested in cloning and creates a new node with the required properties.

Using an fxml template for the node definition is probably the easiest way to do this for node's with static initialization properties - but then, as you state in your question, you don't want to use fxml for this, so you'll have to code your cloning logic in Java.